# String into vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a string which i then want to store in a vector

```
string a = "N\nT\n";
```

after each new line to be in a different cell.

```
std::string ss (".V/\n.F/\n.R/\n");

for(int i = 0; i< ss.size(); i++)
{
    test1.push_back(ss);
}
```

I want to store the `string` in `vector test1`
is this the best way?

Comment: No i want to store the string in `vector test1`

Comment: So you just want to split the string into parts separated by `'\n'`? `strtok` could help with that. (edit): If you just want to store the string, you only need to do it once.

Comment: @chris oh God please don't use `strtok` in C++.

Comment: I've just had that impression from the vast majority of SO answers/comments saying to split a string with strtok. The only alternative I've actually found is string::find with string::substr.

Comment: Is the newline to be discarded?

Comment: @chris `std::getline` can be used instead (you can specify your own delimiter), and you won't have to deal with all that C-string crap.

Comment: Good point, forgot it does more than just newlines. Funny I've never seen anyone say anything about it in place of strtok though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code won't work; it'll store the string `ss.size()` times in the vector.

You might want to use a string stream to split the string:

```
std::stringstream stream(ss);
std::string line;
while (std::getline(stream, line)) {
  test1.push_back(line);
}
```

Note that the newline character will be discarded. If you want to keep it, `push_back(line + "\n");`.

Comment: If you're splitting on newline characters, then this is great.  For any other character(s), you'll need a different solution.

Comment: @aldo `std::getline(stream, line, '\t')`, just to given an example that proves you wrong.

Comment: Wow, I guess I've not used `getline` enough to realize you can specify any delimiter you want.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Boost::split will do this for you. See usage details here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3184031

Answer (score 2):

If the newline can be discarded then you could use `std::copy()`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string ss(".V/\n.F/\n.R/\n");
    std::istringstream in(ss);
    std::vector<std::string> test1;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(in),
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
              std::back_inserter(test1));

    std::for_each(test1.begin(),
                  test1.end(),
                  [](const std::string& s)
                  { 
                      std::cout << s << "\n";
                  });
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
.V/
.F/
.R/
```

Answer (score 0):

This certainly isn't the best way, because it doesn't work. This just pushes `ss.size()` instances of the `std::string` in the vector.

You can use the `find` and `substr` methods to partition the string and push them in the array. (not gonna write the actual code though, might be a good exercise).